# Error while installing Textblob for python

Tags: python, textblob

I'm trying to install textblob but I always get this error. My Python version is 2.7.10

[image]

Comment: Do you need to be using python 2.7?  Although python 2.7 is still available on many computers, most new projects would use version 3.  What happens if you run `pip3 install textblob` ?  (many systems designate `pip3` as the Python 3 version of pip)

Comment: Not sure if this changes anything at all, but the [documentation](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) specifies users to invoke `pip install -U textblob`.

Comment: just install python3 in your system